# How do I access the inner tag with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<wd:Employee_Name wd:Descriptor="John Doe"><wd:ID wd:type="WID">09300cd006150</wd:ID></wd:Employee_Name>
```

I would like to get John Doe. Even though it seems simple I am struggling therefore posting here.

```
soup.find_all('Employee_Name')[0].text
```

gives me the `09300cd006150`

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Use `.Descriptor` to access the attribute.

Comment: Hi @Barmar thanks for your reply but it doesn't output anything. Tried soup.find_all('Employee_Name')[0].Descriptor

Comment: Try this print("".join(BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser").strings))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `wd:Descriptor` is an attribute, `get()` method should be used to retrieve it:

```
xml = '''<root xmlns:wd="http://wd">
<wd:Employee_Name wd:Descriptor="John Doe">
<wd:ID wd:type="WID">09300cd006150</wd:ID>
</wd:Employee_Name></root>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
name = soup.find_all('Employee_Name')[0]
print(name.get('wd:Descriptor'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alexandra!!! it worked :)

I am really happy, You are the best

Comment: Due to reputation point I am not able to accept it as answer